# Shortcut to create hotkeys in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word, at least from 2019, it's somehow possible to make the cursor became like a Command symbol (⌘); if then the user clicks on any button (bold, center, etc.), Word directly opens the "Assign hotkey" dialogue relative to that function; there is a keyboard hotkey to activate this function, but I can't remember it and I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remember it: if you press `Ctrl + Alt + +` **on numeric pad**, the cursor changes to `⌘`; click on any button and the Customize Keyboard dialogue for that function will appear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can use built-in ways to create custom keyboard shortcuts according to [Customize keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d); [Create a custom keyboard shortcut for Office for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-office-for-mac-6bbeb90e-96d9-4e03-b199-fc026ebdc321).

For more information, read [Keyboard shortcuts in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?ui=en-us&rs=en-ie&ad=ie#PickTab=macOS).